# Select case with array

Tags: php, arrays, switch-statement

How can I write a select case with an array to check form validation?

this is my code:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$array = array($name,$email,$message);

switch($array[]) {
    case empty($array[0]):
        error = "name";
        break;
    case empty($array[1]):
        error =  "email";
        break;
    case empty($array[2]):
        error = "message";
}
```

Then, I would like to write code to have this result:
if name is empty:
*"Please fill in your name"* 
if email is empty:
*"Please fill in your email"* 
if name and email is empty:
*"Please fill your name and email"* 
if name and email and message is empty:
*"Please fill in your name, email and message"*

Comment: If you want to concat your error messages, you should better use if - if else statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for a grammatically correct solution:

```
$empty = array();
$fields = array('name', 'email', 'message');
foreach ($fields as $key => $value){
    if(empty($_POST[$value])) $empty[] = $value;
}
$error_msg = '';
$count = count($empty);
$cnct = ', ';
if ($count > 0){
    $error_msg = 'Please fill in your ';
}
foreach ($empty as $key => $value){
    if ($key == $count - 2){
        $cnct = ' and ';
    }elseif($key == $count - 1){
        $cnct = '.';
    }
    $error_msg .= $value.$cnct;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I was searching for :)

Answer (score 3):

You want to concat your messages, so better use if statements:

```
$error = "Please fill in: ";

if (empty($array[0]))
    $error .= "name ";
if (empty($array[1]))
    $error .= "email ";
if (empty($array[2]))
    $error .= "message ";
```

The `.=` will concat the string to the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$error="Please fill in your ";

$array = array('name'=>$name,'email'=>$email,'message'=>$message);
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    if(empty($value)){
        $error.=','.$key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simply write:

```
$error = "Please fill in: ";

if (empty($array[0]))
    $error.= "name ";
if (empty($array[1]))
    $error.=  "email ";
if (empty($array[2]))
    $error.= "message";
```

A switch isn't made for what you want to do.

Comment: This will only display the message for one field.  Need to be able to error on more than one.

Comment: case would do the same. If you want to error on more then one then drop the elses and append the error to the string

Comment: @BernhardPoiss: Actually no. It's a coincidence, I started editing it right after the first comment and was just ... distracted with something else before posting the edit.

Comment: @BernhardPoiss Doesn't look like it was a copy-and-paste, as it has a missing `.=` operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a variable expression in `case` statement of `switch` block.

**A switch case must have a constant expression in many languages including `php`. So, something like a variable or function call doesn't work.**

You better use `conditionals` for this.

Your code is also missing `$` symbol for variable `error`.

Do this instead:

```
  $name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$array = array($name,$email,$message);

    $error="Please fill in your ";
    if(empty($array[0])){
        $error.= "\nname";
        }
    if(empty($array[1])){
        $error.="\nemail";
        };
    if(empty($array[2])){
        $error.= "\nmessage";
    }
   echo $error;
```